# How to use custom url for category in Wordress?

Tags: wordpress

How to change Category URL, I mean my default category URL is **[www.example.com/category/demo](http://www.example.com/category/demo)** or **[www.example.com/category/demo2](http://www.example.com/category/demo2)**. But I want to use [www.example.com/**eligibility/demo](http://www.example.com/**eligibility/demo)** for some categories and for some categories [www.example.com/**location/demo2](http://www.example.com/**location/demo2)**. How to use these types of URL for category or Tags?

Comment: Why don't you create parent category terms for `eligibility` and `location` and have children categories for `demo`, `demo2`, etc?

Comment: Oh! yes it works. Thank You @ disinfor